# vim -R /dev/random

Tags: vim, less

I am on the verge of doing `alias less='vim -R'` for the convenience of being able to scroll with my multitouchpad.

However, I like that `less -f` can view even files like `/dev/random` that are not regular files.

How do I hack `vim -R` so it can read-only non-regular files too?

Comment: What terminal do you use? I can use the scrollwheel in `less` (Ubuntu 10.10 / Gnome Terminal).

Comment: iTerm 2 on Lion

Comment: On the Mac, I have a SIMBL plugin called MouseTerm that allows to use the scrollwheel in `less` or `vim` in Terminal.app. iTerm2 is supposed to support the mouse but I see no mention of the scrollwheel. It looks like an iTerm2 limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
head -c 10 /dev/random | vim -b '+set bt=nowrite' -
```

- **`-b`** *binary mode*
- **`+set bt=nowrite`** *no warning when quit without save*
- **`-`** *read stdin*

To get 100 bytes, you can change `10` to `100`.

Comment: Which part of this passes the non-regular file as an argument to vim?

Comment: The `-` at the end makes vim accept input from stdin. I often do things like `grep pattern file.txt | vim -R -` so that I can then use vim's search on my grep results.